# I want to know how to create dynamically incremental letters "A, B, C" as labels on my windows form

Tags: vb.net

I have a movie theater seating project that dynamically creates checkboxes as seats.  I dynamically create labels across the top and down the right side of the checkboxes that represents the seats (alpha) and rows (numbers).  Currently I have numbers across the top and I want letters i.e. A, B, C, D.

Here is my code

```
Public Class frmSeating
    ' Declare two dynamic arrays to store the created CheckBox and Label
    ' control instances. The array named chkSeats is a 2-dimensional array
    ' and the array lblRow is a one dimensional array.
    Private chkSeats(,) As System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    Private lblRow() As System.Windows.Forms.Label
    Private lblSeat() As System.Windows.Forms.Label

    ' The following constants improve readibility by defining the
    ' standard size of each check box, and the number of seats and rows
    ' for each airplane type.
    Private Const cintCheckBoxHeight As Integer = 23
    Private Const cintCheckBoxWidth As Integer = 23

    Private Const cintABCSeats As Integer = 20
    Private Const cintABCRows As Integer = 20

    Private Const cintCBSSeats As Integer = 26
    Private Const cintCBSRows As Integer = 30

    Private Const cintNBCSeats As Integer = 10
    Private Const cintNBCRows As Integer = 25

    ' The variables mintFull and mintEmpty store the number of
    ' occupied and empty seats in the theater.
    Private mintFull As Integer
    Private mintEmpty As Integer

    ' pntCurrent is used to create a Point structure.
    Private pntCurrent As System.Drawing.Point

    ' All of the work takes place in the ConfigureSeating procedure. This
    ' procedure is called by the constructor. See the New procedure in the
    ' Windows Form Designer generated code.
    Private Sub ConfigureSeating(ByVal TheaterType As String)

        ' Variables to store the current seat and the current row.
        Dim pintSeatCurrent, pintRowCurrent As Integer

        ' The Select Case statement configures the airplane based on the
        ' type of airplane. This value is passed to the procedure, and is
        ' obtained from the argument passed through the constructor.
        Select Case TheaterType


            Case "ABC Theater"
                ' Redimension the arrays containing the check boxes and 
                ' labels based on the current Theater configuration.
                ReDim chkSeats(cintABCSeats, cintABCRows)
                ReDim lblRow(cintABCRows)
                ReDim lblSeat(cintABCSeats)

                ' Define the number of empty seats.
                mintEmpty = cintABCSeats * cintABCRows

                ' Create each check box representing a seat.
                For pintSeatCurrent = 0 To cintABCSeats - 1
                    For pintRowCurrent = 0 To cintABCRows - 1
                        pntCurrent = New Point((pintSeatCurrent + 1) * cintCheckBoxWidth, _
                            (pintRowCurrent + 1) * cintCheckBoxHeight)
                        Call CreateCheckBox(pintSeatCurrent, pintRowCurrent, pntCurrent)
                    Next
                Next

                'Create the labels to identify the rows.
                For pintRowCurrent = 0 To cintABCRows - 1
                    Call CreateRowLabel(pintRowCurrent)
                    lblRow(pintRowCurrent).Left = 490
                    lblRow(pintRowCurrent).Top = (pintRowCurrent + 1) * cintCheckBoxHeight
                    lblRow(pintRowCurrent).Height = 15
                    lblRow(pintRowCurrent).Width = 25
                Next
                'Create the labels to identify the columns
                For pintSeatCurrent = 0 To cintABCSeats - 1
                    Call CreateSeatLabel(pintSeatCurrent)
                    lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Left = (pintSeatCurrent + 1) * cintCheckBoxHeight
                    lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Top = 1
                    lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Height = 15
                    lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Width = 25
                Next

            Case "CBS Theater"

                ReDim chkSeats(cintCBSSeats, cintCBSRows)
                ReDim lblRow(cintCBSRows)
                ReDim lblSeat(cintCBSSeats)

                mintEmpty = cintCBSSeats * cintCBSRows

                For pintSeatCurrent = 0 To cintCBSSeats - 1
                    For pintRowCurrent = 0 To cintCBSRows - 1
                        pntCurrent = New Point((pintSeatCurrent + 1) * cintCheckBoxWidth, _
                            (pintRowCurrent + 1) * cintCheckBoxHeight)
                        Call CreateCheckBox(pintSeatCurrent, pintRowCurrent, pntCurrent)
                    Next
                Next

                For pintRowCurrent = 0 To cintCBSRows - 1
                    Call CreateRowLabel(pintRowCurrent)

                    lblRow(pintRowCurrent).Left = 625
                    lblRow(pintRowCurrent).Top = (pintRowCurrent + 1) * cintCheckBoxHeight
                    lblRow(pintRowCurrent).Height = 15
                    lblRow(pintRowCurrent).Width = 25
                Next

                For pintSeatCurrent = 0 To cintCBSSeats - 1
                    Call CreateSeatLabel(pintSeatCurrent)
                    lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Left = (pintSeatCurrent + 1) * cintCheckBoxHeight
                    lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Top = 1
                    lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Height = 15
                    lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Width = 25
                Next

            Case "NBC Theater"

                ReDim chkSeats(cintNBCSeats, cintNBCRows)
                ReDim lblRow(cintNBCRows)
                ReDim lblSeat(cintNBCSeats)

                mintEmpty = cintNBCSeats * cintNBCRows

                For pintSeatCurrent = 0 To cintNBCSeats - 1
                    For pintRowCurrent = 0 To cintNBCRows - 1
                        pntCurrent = New Point((pintSeatCurrent + 1) * cintCheckBoxWidth, _
                            (pintRowCurrent + 1) * cintCheckBoxHeight)
                        Call CreateCheckBox(pintSeatCurrent, pintRowCurrent, pntCurrent)
                    Next
                Next

                For pintRowCurrent = 0 To cintNBCRows - 1
                    Call CreateRowLabel(pintRowCurrent)

                    lblRow(pintRowCurrent).Left = 255
                    lblRow(pintRowCurrent).Top = (pintRowCurrent + 1) * cintCheckBoxHeight
                    lblRow(pintRowCurrent).Height = 15
                    lblRow(pintRowCurrent).Width = 25
                Next

                For pintSeatCurrent = 0 To cintNBCSeats - 1
                    Call CreateSeatLabel(pintSeatCurrent)
                    lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Left = (pintSeatCurrent + 1) * cintCheckBoxHeight
                    lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Top = 1
                    lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Height = 15
                    lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Width = 25
                Next
        End Select

    End Sub

    ' The CreateCheckBox procedure is responsible for actually creating
    ' each CheckBox control instance and adding a reference to the array.
    ' The current seat and row are passed as arguments, along with the 
    ' position of the check box.
    Private Sub CreateCheckBox(ByVal pintSeatCurrent As Integer, ByVal pintRowcurrent As Integer, ByVal pnt As Point)

        ' Create an instance of the CheckBox control and make it visible.
        chkSeats(pintSeatCurrent, pintRowcurrent) = New CheckBox()
        chkSeats(pintSeatCurrent, pintRowcurrent).Visible = True

        ' Define the size of the CheckBox control instance by creating an 
        ' instance of the Size structure and assigning a value to the Size
        ' property.
        chkSeats(pintSeatCurrent, pintRowcurrent).Size = _
            New System.Drawing.Size(cintCheckBoxWidth, cintCheckBoxHeight)

        ' Define the position of the CheckBox control instance.
        chkSeats(pintSeatCurrent, pintRowcurrent).Location = pnt

        ' Add the event handler for the newly created CheckBox control instance. 
        ' The procedure named chkSeats_CheckChanged will handle the CheckedChanged event for
        ' all of the created check boxes.
        AddHandler chkSeats(pintSeatCurrent, pintRowcurrent).CheckedChanged, _
            AddressOf chkseats_CheckedChanged

        ' Finally, add the newly creted CheckBox control instance to the Controls 
        ' collection for the Panel. Note that by adding the control instance to the
        ' Controls collection of the Panel rather than the form, the control instances
        ' will be contained by the Panel. The reason is simple. The CheckBox control
        ' instances will scroll with the Panel instead of the form.
        Me.pnlSeats.Controls.Add(chkSeats(pintSeatCurrent, pintRowcurrent))
    End Sub

    ' The CreateLabel procedure is responsible for actually creating each
    ' Label control instance and adding a reference to the array.
    Private Sub CreateRowLabel(ByVal pintRowCurrent As Integer)
        lblRow(pintRowCurrent) = New Label()
        lblRow(pintRowCurrent).Visible = True
        lblRow(pintRowCurrent).Text = (pintRowCurrent + 1).ToString()
        Me.pnlSeats.Controls.Add(lblRow(pintRowCurrent))
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateSeatLabel(ByVal pintSeatCurrent As Integer)
        lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent) = New Label()
        lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Visible = True
        lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Text = (pintSeatCurrent + 1).ToString()
        Me.pnlSeats.Controls.Add(lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent))
    End Sub


    ' The CheckedChanged event handler is a multicast event handler and
    ' handles the CheckedChanged event for all of the CheckBox control instances.
    ' The statements in the event handler update the number of full or empty
    ' seats in the theater.
    Private Sub chkseats_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        ' Declare a varible to store the CheckBox.
        Dim chkCurrent As System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox

        ' Again, because sender is of type System.Object, explicitly convert
        ' the argument to a check box using the CType function
        chkCurrent = CType(sender, System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox)

        ' If the check box is checked, increment the number of occupied seats
        ' and decrement the number of empty seats. If the check box is not checked,
        ' then do the reverse.
        Select Case chkCurrent.Checked
            Case True
                mintFull += 1
                mintEmpty -= 1
            Case False
                mintFull -= 1
                mintEmpty += 1
        End Select

        ' Display the results in the labels.
        lblFull.Text = mintFull.ToString()
        lblEmpty.Text = mintEmpty.ToString()
    End Sub


    ' Uncheck all of the check boxes by enumerating the Controls collection of the Panel.
    Private Sub mmuSeatsClear_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles mmuSeatsClear.Click

        Dim ctlCurrent As Control
        Dim chkCurrent As CheckBox

        ' The For Each loop enumerates the Controls collection for the 
        ' Panel rather than the form.
        For Each ctlCurrent In pnlSeats.Controls
            ' Check that the type of the control instance is a CheckBox. 
            ' Labels are also contained by the Panel. If the control instance
            ' is a CheckBox, then remove the check mark by setting the Checked property
            ' to False.
            If TypeOf (ctlCurrent) Is System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox Then
                chkCurrent = CType(ctlCurrent, System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox)
                chkCurrent.Checked = False
            End If
        Next
        lblFull.Text = ""
        lblEmpty.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub mmuFileExit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles mmuFileExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: We’d appreciate if you could post only the **relevant** code. As it stands we’re faced with a wall of text of almost completely irrelevant information that takes time and effort to work through. As a consequence I’ve got no idea what the actual question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the Char representation of the ascii value :

```
Private Sub CreateSeatLabel(ByVal pintSeatCurrent As Integer)
    lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent) = New Label()
    lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Visible = True
    lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent).Text = Chr(pintSeatCurrent + 65)
    Me.pnlSeats.Controls.Add(lblSeat(pintSeatCurrent))
End Sub
```

`65` is the value representing `A` character in [ASCII Chart](http://www.idautomation.com/product-support/ascii-chart-char-set.html). Everytime the index increases by 1 you will get the next alphabetic character.

Comment: Thank you AbZy, You nailed it and it works perfectly. Thank you.